# Full linux account rename

Tags: linux, user-accounts, administration

I want to create a "generic" version of my Linux install, using a "generic" user account name (e.g. to create a new distro). One approach, of course, would be to start from scratch, reinstall and create a new UID=1000 account / GID.

I'm wondering though if it's possible to convert a running system to such a generic version. This would involve at least

- replacing the username / groupname in `/etc/passwd`, shadow, group files
- renaming the `/home/user`; perhaps add a hardlink to the old username initially -- I'm not sure having a symlinked `$HOME` won't create problems
- replacing the username in user's dot-files (including `.local`, `.config`, xfce / whatever etc)
- (??) change binary config files (dconf?)

Anything else? Possible negative consequences?

Comment: There is no way to know where the user name might have crept into. Short of a (dangerous!, think binaries and changed name lengths) global search and replace (which will overlook any compressed contents), no can really do.

Comment: there are tools to dump the standard binary files (like dconf), but I'd need to figure out "all" possible binary config files